# How to trim float64 value to particular decimal points in GO?

Tags: go

I want to trim latitude and longitude of address upto 5 decimal points.
latitude and longitude are of type **float64** I have created a function round the value. 
My function is like this::

```
func DoubleRoundFive(val float64) float64 {
    formattedVal := fmt.Sprintf("%.5f", val)
    roundedVal, _ := strconv.ParseFloat(formattedVal, 64)
    return roundedVal
}
```

Output and usage::

```
DoubleRoundFive(76.70289609999999)
```

Output::

```
76.7029
```

But I just want to trim the value upto 5 decimal points. I want output as **76.70289** . Is it possible in GO??
I want exact 5 decimal values because I am using this for latitude longitude.
This is a GO playground [Link](https://play.golang.org/p/hsEwY3w5NkG)

Comment: I just want to trim decimal value to 5 place

Comment: I want exact latitude longitude to calculate the distance , that's why I just want value upto exact 5 decimal points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

)

func main() {
    val := DoubleRoundFive(76.70289609999999)
    fmt.Println(val)
}

func DoubleRoundFive(val float64) float64 {
    valInt := int64(val*100000)
    val = float64(valInt)/100000
    return val
}
```

Go Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/O_H_buvJtDO

Comment: check this for value "40.7564017". It gives only four digit value for this value??
For every type of number I want exact five decimal points whether its 0 or something else. Is it possible?

Comment: In float, `40.7564`, `40.75640`, `40.75640000` they all are same. check here: https://play.golang.org/p/COB_J8q1W5S.